# Show/Hide div with sub div using button click JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can I make a div show/hide with a sub div like:

```
<div class="form-group" style="display:none;">
    <div id="tabicon" style="display:none;">
        <span>ICON</span>
    </div>
    <div id="tabimages" style="display:none;">
        <span>IMAGES</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="button_tab">
    <input type="button" name="btnicon" value="icon">
    <input type="button" name="btnimages" value="images">
</div>
```

So that when I click `btnicon`, the tab icon is opened/showing and
when I click `btnimages`, the tab images is opened/showing, with the tab icon hidden?

Comment: If parent is hidden, there is no way child is gonna appear!

Comment: OP should include all relevant code like html js css :)

Comment: @RayonDabre in default the parent div is hidden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it with simple jquery by defining which div has to shown on which button click.

```
$('btnicon').on('click', function(){
    $('#tabicon,.form-group').show();
});

$('btnicon').on('click', function(){
    $('#tabimages,.form-group').show();
});
```

**If you want to show this div and hide another div on button click use this**

```
$('btnicon').on('click', function(){
    $('#tabicon,.form-group').show();
    $('#tabimages').hide();
});

$('btnicon').on('click', function(){
    $('#tabimages,.form-group').show();
    $('#tabicon').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('input[name=btnicon]').click(function(){//icon click
$('#tabicon').show()//show icon div
$('#tabimages').hide()//hide image div

}).click()//manually call click to show icon div on load
$('input[name=btnimages]').click(function(){//image click
$('#tabicon').hide()//hide icon div
$('#tabimages').show()//show image div

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <div id="tabicon" style="display:none;">
        <span>ICON</span>
    </div>
    <div id="tabimages" style="display:none;">
        <span>IMAGES</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="button_tab">
    <input type="button" name="btnicon" value="icon">
    <input type="button" name="btnimages" value="images">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : You have to remove `display:none` from parent div as this will hide all its child elements. Create button handler and use `.show()` and `.hide()` methods as shown below -

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div id="tabicon" style="display:none;">
        <span>ICON</span>
    </div>
    <div id="tabimages" style="display:none;">
        <span>IMAGES</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="button_tab">
    <input type="button" name="btnicon" value="icon">
    <input type="button" name="btnimages" value="images">
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
   $('input[name="btnicon"]').click(function(){
      $('#tabicon').show();
      $('#tabimages').hide();
   });
   $('input[name="btnimages"]').click(function(){
      $('#tabicon').hide();
      $('#tabimages').show();
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the "hidden" properties directly to the elements you are hiding/displaying you could set the properties through adding and removing classes to the parent container. "form-group".

```
.parent-class, #tabicon, #tabimage {
  display: none;
}

.parent-class.icon-class, .parent-class.image-class {
  display: block;
}

.parent-class.icon-class #tabicon{
  display: block;
}

.parent-class.image-class #tabimage {
  display: block;
}
```

This way when you add the class to the parent container you will show hide the parent container based on it having either of the childs active. The current child you have set to active will also be visible based on which classes are active in the parent container.

If none of the childs are active the parent container will be hidden.